# Confusion on do-while loop

Tags: java

Here is my **Code**

```
import java.util.*;
public class dowhile
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{
Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number of # to be displayed: ");
int tim = kb.nextInt();

     String hash = "#";

     do
     {
        System.out.println(hash);
        hash = hash + 1;
        } while (hash.equals(5));
     }
}
```

I am confused on how to display number of **#** after asked by the user..

I know `hash.equals(5)` does not make sense.
how can i fix this code?

Any one please give the suggestion to me.

Comment: You have syntax error, Why you put while inside do?
Try this:do
     {
        System.out.println(hash);
        hash = hash + 1;
     } while (hash.equals(tim));

Answer (score 0):

Declare one int variable before the loop. Increment number by one in do and check then number in while loop is will print your desired output.

```
 int i=0;
 do
 {
    System.out.println(hash);
    i=i + 1;
 } while (i<tim);
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, some comments and/or explanation would be nice. That will help other users as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tim` as a counter, and *decrement* it before testing if it's greater than `0`. Something like,

```
int tim = kb.nextInt();
do {
    System.out.print("#");
} while (--tim > 0);
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Apache commons-lang3 which has [StringUtils.repeat(String, int)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat(java.lang.String,%20int))

**Parameters**:
str - the String to repeat, may be null
repeat - number of times to repeat str, negative treated as zero

Answer (score 0):

`hash` is the string that you are going to print, so you should never change its value like this:

```
hash = hash + 1; // this does not actually compile anyway.
```

To keep track of how many times you still need to print, you need an `int` variable. As you can see, `tim` is an `int` and it already has the user input stored in it. Let's use `tim` as our counter.

Each time you print a `#` you decrease `tim` by 1. And in the loop condition, you write `tim > 0`. This will make the loop run as long as `tim` is greater than 0.

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number of # to be displayed: ");
int tim = kb.nextInt();

String hash = "#";

do {
    System.out.println(hash);
    tim--; // this is equivalent to tim = tim - 1;, in case you did not know
} while (tim > 0);
```

However, I don't think using a `do-while` loop is suitable here. What if the user entered 0? One `#` will still be printed. That's no good isn't it?

I suggest a for loop here:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number of # to be displayed: ");
int tim = kb.nextInt();

String hash = "#";

for (int i = 0 ; i < tim ; i++) {
    System.out.println(hash);
}
```